# How to add filter on RMarkdown file to filter through all DT data tables?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

**Context**:
I have a markdown document with 14 tabs which all include [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) tables. My stakeholder is requesting if I can create one filter for all tabs in the document. Screenshot below for some additional context

[image]

I understand you can include filters on DT tables, and I have them included. However, that only filters to one table. I am looking for one filter to change all tables within the document.

Code below:

```
data <-  qc_sales %>%
  mutate(Call_For_Price = ifelse(CFP_FLG == 1, "TRUE", "FALSE"), MGD_ACCT_FLG = ifelse(MGD_ACCT_FLG == "Y", "YES", "NO")) %>% 
 filter(    STR_NBR != '8119'
          , Opened_Quote_Flag == 1
          , LWK_TY_LY_FLG == 'TY'
          , MVNDR_NBR %in% c(vendor_nbr)
          , !SUB_DEPT_NBR %in% c('0025','0028')) %>% 
   select(  QUOTE_DT
          , STORE = STR_NBR
          , ST_CD 
          , BRANCH = BRANCH_NM
          , MANAGED_ACCOUNT = MGD_ACCT_FLG
          , MKT_NBR
          , MKT_NM
          , ASSC_FRST_NM
          , ASSC_LAST_NM
          , STORE_PHONE_NBR = MAIN_STR_PHN_NBR
          , MVNDR_NBR
          , MVNDR_NM
          , SUB_DEPT_NBR
          , SUB_DEPT_DESC
          , PROD_DESC
          , ADD_PROD_DESC
          , Manufacturer_Model_NBR
          , Call_For_Price 
          , QUOTE_DLRS) %>% 
  group_by( QUOTE_DT
          , STORE
          , ST_CD
          , BRANCH
          , MANAGED_ACCOUNT
          , MKT_NBR
          , MKT_NM
          , ASSC_FRST_NM
          , ASSC_LAST_NM
          , STORE_PHONE_NBR
          , MVNDR_NBR
          , MVNDR_NM
          , SUB_DEPT_NBR
          , SUB_DEPT_DESC
          , PROD_DESC
          , ADD_PROD_DESC
          , Manufacturer_Model_NBR
          , Call_For_Price
            ) %>% 
  summarise(QUOTE_DOLLARS =sum(QUOTE_DLRS)
          , SUB_DEPT = MAX(CONCAT(SUB_DEPT_NBR,'-', SUB_DEPT_DESC))
          , MARKET_NBR_NM = MAX(CONCAT(MKT_NBR,'-', MKT_NM))
          , ASSOCIATE_NM = MAX(CONCAT(ASSC_FRST_NM,' ', ASSC_LAST_NM))
          , MVNDR = MAX(CONCAT(MVNDR_NBR,'-', MVNDR_NM))) %>%  
  mutate(QUOTE_DOLLARS = round(QUOTE_DOLLARS, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(QUOTE_DOLLARS = paste0('$',QUOTE_DOLLARS)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(  QUOTE_DATE = QUOTE_DT
         , STORE
         , STATE = ST_CD
         , BRANCH
         , MANAGED_ACCOUNT
         , STORE_PHONE_NBR
         , ASSOCIATE_NM
         , SUB_DEPT
         , MVNDR
         , MVNDR_NBR
         , PROD_DESC 
         , ADD_PROD_DESC
         , MODEL_NBR = Manufacturer_Model_NBR
         , QC_ORDER_TYPE = Call_For_Price
         , QUOTE_DOLLARS) %>% 
  arrange(desc(QUOTE_DOLLARS)) %>% 
  collect()
  
data$QUOTE_DOLLARS <- currency(data$QUOTE_DOLLARS, digits = 0L)

data <-  data %>%  
  select( QUOTE_DATE 
         , STORE
         , STATE 
         , BRANCH
         , MANAGED_ACCOUNT
         , STORE_PHONE_NBR
         , ASSOCIATE_NM
         , SUB_DEPT
         , MVNDR
         , MVNDR_NBR
         , PROD_DESC 
         , ADD_PROD_DESC
         , MODEL_NBR 
         , QC_ORDER_TYPE 
         , QUOTE_DOLLARS) %>% 
    arrange(desc(QUOTE_DOLLARS)) %>% 
    mutate(QUOTE_DOLLARS = paste0(QUOTE_DOLLARS)) %>% 
    collect()
```

```
data %>% #THIS GENERATES THE DT TABLE WHERE I WOULD LIKE A FILTER TO BE RELELEVANT 
filter(MVNDR_NBR == params$MVNDR_NBR) %>% 
           ungroup() %>%
    select(-MVNDR_NBR, -MVNDR) %>% 
  DT::datatable( 
    filter = 'top',
    extensions = 'Buttons', 
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                   filter = 'top',
                   buttons = c('excel', "csv")))
```

Comment: This is easier to do with "shiny documents", Rmarkdown that are running on a shiny instance (runtime: shiny), see here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-start.html. Because you have to let user choose it means an interactivity that is not fully optimal in basic Rmarkdown. Maybe another way to achieve this is to try with crosstalk package https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/

Comment: This could be doable without the shiny runtime using just javascript.  It would be useful to see the actual rmarkdown code in order to provide a solution.

Comment: Sure, I can share my script @mosk915. See the updated question, thanks !